# PODSCMS + jQuery

Tags: wordpress, podscms

I am modifying a theme and pulling data out of my PODS tables. I also have a custom DBTOXML.php file which is called from index.php using an AJAX call. Since this is a custom file that I put into my wordpress theme, it can't seem to find my Pod class and so I am not able to pull data out of my PODS tables. Any idea how I can make that 'DBTOXML.php' work with PODS?

Here is the complete code for DBTOXML.php

```
<?php
$rwhdata = new Pod('rainwater');
$p = $rwhdata->fetchRecords();
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("Markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
while ($p->fetchRecord()) {
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node); 
    $locString = $p->get_field('location');
    list($latitude,$longitude)=split(',',$locString);
    $newNode->setAttribute("latLocation",$latitude);
    $newNode->setAttribute("longitude",$longitude);

}
echo $dom->saveXML();
?>
```

and this is the jquery call...

```
$.ajax({
                url:'<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/DBTOXML.php';?>',
                type:'POST',
                data:"",
                success:function(results)
                {
                    //Some work here

                }
                });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, you'll want to use the following code to include WP into the page so you can utilize any of the php functions contained in the activated plugins (in this case, Pods):

```
require_once(realpath('../../../wp-load.php'));
```

Answer (score 0):

If the one you've posted is your entire DBTOXML.php code, it won't find your class because you haven't included the necessary PODS files.
Take a look at your main theme page code to see which pods' files are included and try to add them to your page...

Comment: that's the thing... in my index.php i have stripped out all the default code and put in my own HTML and PHP..and there PODS works fine..

Comment: Pods methods and API should be accessible through out any instance of your theme/plugin development. They intended it to be that way. Try moving your code to your functions.php file and see if that works.

Comment: @hsatterwhite - tried it using call_user_func() , am still getting error..please help! urgent and desperate!

Comment: @Sharath Try their Chat. Scott and/or Matt (core devs) are always there and ready to help. http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=podscms

If you move it to your functions.php file in your theme you really shuoldn't have a problem with accessing any pods functionality.

Comment: Concated Scott via chat..and was able to find a solution to my original question.. needed to include 
require_once(realpath('../../../wp-load.php'));
in the new php file

Comment: That's awesome, glad you were able to find a solution :)